# Mapping between UserListId of Google Adwords Api and ResourceName of Ads API

Tags: google-ads-api

We were using Google Adwords API to create an Audience(UserList). Adwords API returns userListId as response. In Google Ads API in order to update the Audience, we need to pass resource Name (as compared to UserListId in Adwords API). How do I go about using Audience(UserList) created in Adwords API using Google Ads API?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation explains how the resource name for each resource is composed. In the case of a [user list](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v10/UserList#resource_name), it's

```
customers/{customer_id}/userLists/{user_list_id}
```

where `customer_id` is the ID of the Ads account and `user_list_id` is the ID you obtained when you created the list.